# Can't use method on an instance variable

Tags: objective-c, foundation

Why doesn't testVariableValues have the method dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *testVariableValues;
```

I'm trying to use the method like so:

```
[self.testVariableValues dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:......]
```

The only method available is `[self.testVariableValues dictionaryWithValuesForKeys...`

I'm new to Objective C and don't have much of an idea about the problem. Something to do with instance methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up class methods and instance methods.

You need to call

```
 self.testVariableValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj1, @"key1"..., nil].
```

Hope that helps.